# video for everybody auto play

Tags: flash, html, url, video

I am using the following code to play a video on my site. at the moment it is set to auto play. What I would like to know is there a way to make the video only auto play if visited from a specific URL. and not auto play if navigated through the site?

code below:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
        <source src="__VIDEO__.MP4"  type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="__VIDEO__.OGV"  type="video/ogg" />
        <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">
            <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=true&amp;controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
            <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
                 title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
    </video>
```

Comment: I am probably asking the impossible.

Comment: I there a way of adding auto play with jquery when a certain url is visited

Comment: I have seen with youtube videos you can specify the time into the video it should start with =41s at the end is there a way with the above script where I can add auto play to the url to make it play???

Comment: If you are in control of the swf (as that's where the majority of coding has to be done to accomplish this, unless your player is already setup to recieve autoPlay or play/stop commands from JS or as passed arguments) then you can do this.   When you say specific URL are talking about the referral URL or the current URL of the page your swf resides in?

Comment: This player does have autoplay="autoplay" as a setting. the code for the player is generated here: http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/. I don't want auto play to work if the video is navigated through the site. I have a email going out and I want a specific url that when visited from the email the video plays

Comment: are you using server side scripting (eg php, asp, jsp)?

Comment: I am afraid the video is in a cms built on coldfusion and I don't have access to the server side stuff

Comment: you'll need to set a cookie, or use the html pages referral header (to see if the last page was not in your domain) to be able to do this

Comment: Thank you, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use JavaScript to check the referral, if it's not from your site then set autoPlay to true.

ex:

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf("mydomain.com") < 0){
    //set auto play
}
```

or

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf("mydomain.com") > -1){
    //tell the swf to play your video
}
```

Ideally you'd want to check this with server side code and just spit out the html accordingly. with JS you'll have to either create the flash object via JS code (something like swfObject), or set autoPlay as false all the time and invoke a play function (if it exists) after the fact when you check the referrer.